# Est-ce que c'est impoli de parler sans le « ne » si votre ami parle avec « ne + pas » ?

Tags: négation, politesse, langage-informel

J'espère que c'est une question simple, mais tout comme le fait qu'il est impoli de tutoyer quelqu'un quand on vous vouvoie, est-ce qu'il est impoli de parler sans le « ne » avant un « pas »  si l'autre le fait ?

Les situations auxquelles je pense sont comme celles-ci (par exemple):

> **Vous**: Pardon, je n'ai pas compris.
>   **Moi**: Ah, t'inquiète pas si tu comprends pas.

Je sais que c'est probablement simple, mais j'habite en Australie et je ne connais pas beaucoup de Français donc je ne peux pas vraiment demander à quelqu'un.

Merci ! De même, n'hésitez pas à me corriger sur mon orthographe et ma grammaire parce que je ne suis qu'un étudiant.

---

I hope that this is a simple question, but much like the reality that it is impolite to address someone as “tu” when they address you as “vous”, is it also impolite to speak without the “ne” before a “pas” if the other actually does ?

The situations that I'm talking about are like this one (for example):

> **Vous**: Pardon, je n'ai pas compris.
>   **Moi**: Ah, t'inquiète pas si tu comprends pas.

I know that it's probably a simple question, but I live in Australia and I don't know many French people so I can't really ask anybody but turn to here.

Thank you! Also, please feel free to correct me on my writing and grammar because I am only a student.

Comment: Je suggère que vous précisiez ce que vous voulez dire par " beaucoup comme la réalité que c'est impoli". Je pense qu'il manque un verbe. J'ai compris cette phrase comme "beaucoup disent que c'est impoli de tutoyer". Est-ce cela ?

Comment: @Greg Hmm... Merci Greg! Peut-être je devrais le récrire en anglais ausssi ? Par cela, je veux dire "much like the reality that it is impolite to address as « tu », with someone if they address you as «vous»". Je pense que vous avez manqué les mots par la suite.

Comment: @Greg Ahhh ! Ouais ! Pardon, je pense que je confonds « pour » et « de » de temps en temps. Je l'ai corrigé.

Comment: OK, alors je suggère plutôt d'utiliser l'expression "tout comme" pour "much like": *tout comme le fait qu'il est impoli de s'adresser à quelqu'un par "tu"*, etc.

Comment: Comme demandé, je me suis permis de corriger les quelques fautes dans votre question (regardez les "edits" que j'ai faits). Bravo pour vos efforts, la faute la plus visible était *me corrigez* au lieu de *corrigez-moi*.

Comment: @Greg Merci beaucoup pour votre aide ! Je suis pas à chez moi maintenant mais je vais corriger quand j'arrive.

Comment: Ah, tant pis! Vous m'avez battu !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cela ne sera pas vraiment perçu comme impoli, au pire comme du français familier ou "relâché", en fonction du contexte. En fait, je pense même que dans la grande majorité des cas, les locuteurs ne remarqueront pas que l'autre personne a utilisé le "ne" ou pas, cela passera inaperçu dans le flot de la conversation.

Une petite remarque: il peut y avoir des cas où il est socialement acceptable de répondre avec "tu" à une personne qui a utilisé le "vous": ce seront des cas où il y a une différence de statut entre les deux personnes. Par exemple:

- un enfant et un adulte (s'ils ne se connaissent pas)
- un professeur et un étudiant (mais là, cela peut dépendre de l'école, du professeur, de la relation entre le professeur et l'étudiant, etc.)
- un employé et un supérieur hiérarchique (dans certaines entreprises "old school", mais de mon expérience, je pense que cela a tendance à 
  se perdre)

Par contre, entre par exemple deux inconnus adultes, répondre à un "vous" par un "tu" est en effet impoli, ou alors c'est une marque d'agressivité, par exemple pendant une dispute.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Greg ! En fait je connais de votre remarque (précisément les 1er et 2ème points) mais le 3ème est nouveaux pour moi.